# fillRect or drawImage not activating within update method in java

Tags: java, swing, applet

Hi I've been trying to get rid of my flickering on a JFrame app. Have searched around and seen that setDoubleBuffered(true) can be used for paintComponent of Jpanel, but not paint method of JFrame, nor applets.

Managed to diminish but not eliminate flickering by introducing the instructions this.createbufferstrategy(2) within paint method, and further reduced flickering with the instruction this.setignorerepaint(true) inside paint.

But I finally found an example of code that completely removes flickering and it works by drawing the static elements within the update function.

Tested fillRect within update in an applet and it works, but when copy pasted into a regular java application it does not work there within the jframe's update function.

Here's the code

```
   Graphics graphics;
   Image image;
   public void update(Graphics g)
   {
   if (image == null) {  

   image = createImage(this.getWidth(), this.getHeight());

   graphics = image.getGraphics();  }

   graphics.setColor(Color.blue);

   graphics.fillRect(0,  0,  this.getWidth(),  this.getHeight());

   g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, this);//}
```

With an empty paint function this draws to the screen and fills it with blue in an applet, it also gets rid of flickering.  But in a normal application of jframe it does nothing.

What needs to be done to allow either fillRect or drawImage to work from within update in a non applet regular application environment?

BTW, I'm a bit new to this if the graphics object is being modified itself by calling fillRect, how does that modify the image object?  Because drawImage is necessary for the screen to turn blue.

PS I've tried not using both createbufferedstrategy and setignorerepaint, and nothing changes.

Comment: And why not just use a JPanel to paint to...?

Comment: I would place a System.out in the update method to ensure that the method is being called? I'd also call graphics.dispose before drawing the image...

Comment: Don't override update(). That is old code used for AWT painting. Swing is double buffered by default and that includes the JFrame since it just uses a JPanel as the content pane. The problem is in your code so you need to post a `SSCCE` that demonstrates the problem.

Answer (score 1):

When using `setIgnorePaint(true)`, its not allowing you to mess with the Graphics.
I'm guessing by the looks of your update(Graphics g) parameter, you call that within your paint method, using the paintMethod's graphic g to paint (inside paint method, you call update(g))

If you ignore paint, its not gonna allow you to use the paintComponent's Graphic parameter.
Post all code that includes graphics (Where you made your strategy, where you're calling this method, ect..)

The flickering is a pretty mainstream issue with the strategy, and I can't promise that I'll be able to fix it (my friend brought the problem up to me a while ago, but i didnt care enough to try and figure it out), but that should at least explain why your graphics aren't rendering